# Remove label/label spacing below each MDCInputField

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, mdc-components

I'm trying to get two MDCTextFields (https://material.io/develop/ios/components/textfields/) to stack vertically, one under the other without any spacing.

Here's a visual representation:

[image]

This is what it actually looks in the emulator altho they are constrained to stay close without margin/padding. MDCInputFields adds these spacings for label below each InputField. Is there a way to override this?

[image]

Constraint looks like this, top between email and password with constant 0
within a StackView set to Vertical.
[image]

Comment: Can you show constraints ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan Updated question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1- Drag a UIStackView (vertical) , set centerX , top , width , height and set distribution to fillEqually , confirm spacing is 0

2- Drag the 2 textfields inside it without giving any constraints

3- Hook login button top constraint to the stack view's bottom + 20 and give it centerX

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this does work with a normal UI component but not with MDCTextField. It seems to do something special under the hood at runtime that overrides whatever constraint I set.